# Kentor AuthServices add custom attribute

Tags: c#, kentor-authservices

I am using Kentor AuthServices.OWIN to send a SAML2 request and I am having trouble to configure attribute called **ProviderName**. I can't find it anywhere under the property. Is there any solution to add custom attribute to the AuthRequest?